Prove that two integrating factors define a solution.
I've been toiling away at this proof problem from Chapter 2.4 ending exercises of Differential Equations 3rd ed by Shepley L. Ross, but to no avail.

Show that if $\mu (x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ are integrating factors of $$ M(x, y)\ dx + N(x, y)\ dy = 0 $$ such that $\mu (x, y) / v(x, y)$ is not constant, then $$ \mu (x, y) = cv(x, y) $$ is a solution of the differential equation for every constant $c$.

My approach was that, iff $ \mu (x, y) / v(x, y) = c $ defines a solution for the differential equation then we must have $$ \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x } \left( \frac {u}{v} \right) = M(x, y) $$ $$ \frac{ \partial }{ \partial y } \left( \frac {u}{v} \right) = N(x, y) $$ and therefore must set out to prove it.
On the outset, we have $$ \frac{ \partial }{ \partial y }(\mu M) = \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x }(\mu N) $$ $$ \frac{ \partial }{ \partial y }(v M) = \frac{ \partial }{ \partial y }(v M) $$
A bit of simplification later $$ \mu \left( \frac{ \partial M }{ \partial y } - \frac{ \partial N }{ \partial x } \right) = N(x, y) \frac{ \partial \mu }{ \partial x } - M(x, y) \frac{ \partial \mu }{ \partial y } $$ $$ v \left( \frac{ \partial M }{ \partial y } - \frac{ \partial N }{ \partial x } \right) = N(x, y) \frac{ \partial v }{ \partial x } - M(x, y) \frac{ \partial v }{ \partial y } $$
Doing the obvious and dividing, we have $$ \frac{u}{v} = \frac{ N(x, y) \displaystyle { \frac{ \partial \mu }{ \partial x } - M(x, y) \frac{ \partial \mu }{ \partial y } } }{ N(x, y) \displaystyle{ \frac{ \partial v }{ \partial x } - M(x, y) \frac{ \partial v }{ \partial y } } } $$
At this point, as I did not have any other leads, I decided to try and calculate the x and y partial derivatives. Starting with a deep breath, I set out onto a journey that lasted a good while but did not bring fruitful results. Enough terms did not cancel out and I am out of ideas, please HELP.

Differentiating $\mu(x,y)=cv(x,y)$ with respect to $x$, one obtains
$$
\mu_x+\mu_yy'=c(v_x+v_yy')=\frac{\mu}{v}(v_x+v_yy')
$$
$$
\implies y'=\frac{v\mu_x-\mu v_x}{\mu v_y-v\mu_y}. \tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, from the equations
\begin{align}
\mu(M_y-N_x)&=N\mu_x-M\mu_y, \tag{2} \\
v(M_y-N_x)&=Nv_x-Mv_y, \tag{3}
\end{align}
derived in the OP, one obtains the identity
$$
v(N\mu_x-M\mu_y)=\mu(Nv_x-Mv_y) \implies \frac{\mu v_x-v\mu_x}{\mu v_y-v\mu_y}=\frac{M}{N}. \tag{4}
$$
From $(1)$ and $(4)$ it follows that $\mu(x,y)=cv(x,y)$ satisfies the differential equation $y'=-\frac{M}{N}$, which is equivalent to $Mdx+Ndy=0.$

Thanks, mister!
